# Не получается подключиться к БД через скрипт python

Tags: python, centos, веб-программирование, mariadb

Привет, не могу понять логики работы и куда копать. Сам я новичок в веб-разработке.

Есть web-сервер на CentOS 7. На нём стоит база MariaDB и Python2.7.
Пользователь базы - root, доступ корректен.

Простой скрипт подключения к базе работает без проблем, результаты выводятся из базы в консоль терминала.
Сам скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import mysql.connector as mariadb

user='root'
passb='xxx'
basename='xxx'
mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user=user, password=passb, database=basename)
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")

for field1, field2, field3, field4 in cursor:
   print("Name: {}, Sex: {}, Age: {}, Comment: {},").format(field1,field2,field3,field4)


mariadb_connection.commit()   
mariadb_connection.close()

print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print ("<h1>Test message</h1>")
```

Но если запросить этот скрипт из браузера через форму HTML, таким образом:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/connectbase.py" method="POST" target="_self">
<input type="submit" value="Просмотр" /></form>
```

То в браузере на вызов скрипта можно увидеть **Internal Server Error**, а в логе **/var/log/httpd/error_log** я нахожу:

- [Tue Nov 01 13:47:46.579053 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 1924] [client
  xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx] AH01215: mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (13
  Permission denied), referer: http://mycite.org/
- [Tue Nov 01 13:47:46.586432 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 1924] [client
  xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx] End of script output before headers: show.py, referer: http://mycite.org/

---

Эта проблема появилась после того как я удалил MySQL базу и поставил MariaDB. До смены базы всё работало ОК.
Мне неясна логика сего явления. Ведь доступ к базе должен быть у скрипта. Обмен с базой (запросы) происходит через скрипт. У скрипта есть доступ и в консольном режиме он все отдает корректно. Почему тогда когда я обращаюсь к тому же скрипту, пусть и через веб-форму, мне отдают ошибку о подключении к базе?

Или соединение с базой через веб происходит как-то иначе?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в следующем: включен selinux и не дает доступ к сокету. 
Решение: вырубить.